# Unable to compile C++ thread library on my Ubuntu Linux system

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am unable to compile C++ thread library on my Ubuntu Linux system. With every option I give while compiling I always get this error

Either I compile giving

```
alc:~/practice/C++$ g++ -o thr thr.cpp -lpthread -std=c++11
```

or

```
alc:~/practice/C++$ g++ -o thr thr.cpp -std=c++0x -lpthread
In file included from thr.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread: In constructor ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:138:46: error: ‘__bind_simple’ is not a member of ‘std’
         _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:138:46: note: suggested alternative: ‘__big_div_impl’
         _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                              __big_div_impl
```

This is my C++ program

```
#include <c++/4.9/iostream>
#include <c++/4.9/thread>

using namespace std;

void func_dummy(int N)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i < N ; i++)
        cout << "Thread 1 : function pointer" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    thread thr1(func_dummy, 2);

    thr1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <c++/4.9/iostream>` -- That's odd that you need to specify a path like this for the standard header.  Maybe you should fix your compiler installation so that you don't need to be do this.

Comment: And see [**Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Following on from @PaulMcKenzie's comment, it is possible that the headers under the "4.9" folder include other system files, which will be included from the standard include path. Since those are likely different library versions, you run into problems mixing the headers from the two.

Comment: you shouuld use 
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. The path for the header files were incorrect. I changed the path and it worked.